# draw X charts given an array of X files + add graph title using elements in array + d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

this is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/1/), which I am building on from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

And now I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/16/) where it uses an array to draw 1 chart per each element in the array

```
arr = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data2.tsv"]

for (this_file in arr) {

  d3.tsv(arr[this_file], type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    //draw chart code 

    //add a graph title
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "12px")
      //.style("text-decoration", "underline")  
      .text(arr[this_file] + " - 1");


  });

}
```

But the way this works is that each chart title gets the name from the 2nd name in the array. What I want is the 1st elment name to be the title of chart 1 and the 2nd element to be the title of chart 2... How can this be done? Or do I have a slight misunderstanding here?

My current workaround is to use a `var=ii` to get this to work. here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/17/) but I am just wondering is there a better way, or maybe I need to rewrite it?

Comment: `this_file`, when used within `function(error, data)`, is always set to the value it was the last time your loop executed (i.e. the value of the last element in the array). This is a general javascript issue — not specific to d3. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: tks, so is that my code is faulty or is my work around the best I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid your workaround! Having a global-ish variable `ii` modified as a side effect of a render action (the `ii++` bit) is unclear and can backfire big time. Try this:

```
var arr = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data.tsv", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49714666/data2.tsv"]

for (var this_file in arr) {
  // "createDataHandler" is declared below
  d3.tsv(arr[this_file], type, createDataHandler(arr[this_file]));
}

// This is a function that returns a function. This way, the returned, inner function
// is already scoped to the appropriate "instance of this_file".
// The returned function becomes the "data loaded" handler of d3.tsv
function createDataHandler(fileUrl) {
  // This bit will be executed once per fileUrl (aka this_file)
  // Note how when it executes, the tsv hasn't even began yet loading.
  console.log("Create handler for " + fileUrl);

  return function(error, data) {
    // This bit executes once the TSV associated with each fileUrl (aka this_file)
    // is loaded.

    if (error) throw error;

    //draw chart code 

    //add a graph title
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "12px")

      // instead of this:
      //.text(arr[this_file] + " - 1");

      // you get to use fileUrl:
      .text(fileUrl + " - 1");
  }
}
```

Comment: tks, but this is close [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/18/) the 2nd chart drawn the title is written on top which does not look right. can this be fixed?

Comment: correction that was my mistake, I was duplicating writing to the chart title. here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ygmkvreb/19/)

Comment: @HattrickNZ sorry, but can you rephrase your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: don't worry you were right with your first answer. my fiddles should hopefully show this.